# how to use an xpath that use to() function in selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, google-chrome, xpath

how can I use this command `$x("//div[@class='card-info__container']/div[3]/a").at(0)` in selenium for finding the element I need.

I know that I can use `findElement(By.xpath())` using this `//div[@class='card-info__container']/div[3]/a`  but what should I do with the `at()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.at(0)` is not a part of XPath expression here and you can not use it with Selenium.
In the expression you showing in your question the `$x` is applied on the `"//div[@class='card-info__container']/div[3]/a"` Xpath expression and then `.at(0)` is applied on the result of the previous action.
**UPD**
So, in order to locate the first "Download Datasheet" button you can use this  XPath locator:

```xml
(//div[@class='card-info__container']/div[3]/a)[1]
```

To access the second button you can use

```xml
(//div[@class='card-info__container']/div[3]/a)[2]
```

etc.

Comment: what should I use instead because I use the at(0) to point the element I need?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? If possibly please share more your code and the link to the page you are working on

Comment: I want to click a specific 'card-info_container' the problem is that without any ID or difference in the element I use the xpath to find them but I need the at(0) to point the element I need? I also tried to write the xpath like this: "//div[@class='card-info__container']/div[3]/a[0]" but it doesn't work

Comment: There is no such function with Xpath. You can use `[1]` to select an element from the list thought. Can you share a link to the page?

Comment: I see. So, you want to click on the first "Download datasheet" button?

Comment: yes, I want to click that

Comment: OK, see my updated answer. You will probably have to use scroll to scroll the page up to access that element.